# Modal content not loaded using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make an instruction page about proxy settings for the users.

I have listed procedures step by step for each browser and put a link to picture that shows how it is done.

I want to show the picture in an PHP file which getting required image file and showing on the page according to its parameters `s` and `b` which are stand for `s: step` and `b: browser`.

My jQuery is

```
$(function() {

    $("a[id^='proxy_']").click(
            function() {  
                var b = $(this).data("b");
                var s = $(this).data("s");
                $("#proxy_modal_title").html("Proxy Settings");
                $("#proxy_modal_body").load("images/proxy_settings/proxy.php?b=" + b + "&s=" + s);
            });

});
```

It should load `./images/proxy_settings/proxy.php?b=ie&s=1` but nothing happens.
And HTML is ( a part only)

```
<ol>
    <li>Click on Settings <a id="proxy_ie_step_01" data-s="1" data-b="ie" href="#proxyModal" data-toggle="modal" title="Show picture"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span></a>
    </li>
    <li>Select Internet Options <a id="proxy_ie_step_02" data-s="2" data-b="ie" href="#proxyModal" data-toggle="modal" title="Show picture"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span> </a>
    </li>
    <!-- goes on -->
</ol>
```

And the modal is here:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="proxyModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="zkanoca" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="proxy_modal_title"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="proxy_modal_body">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Proxy.php file content is here:

```
if (isset($_GET['b']) && isset($_GET['s']))
{
    echo '<img src="proxy_setting_' . $_GET['b'] . '_' . $_GET['s'] . '.png " />';
}
else
{
    exit;
}
```

Modal opens up but either modal title or modal content are empty. I have checked it with Firebug but cannot see any error.

I have tried to put an `alert("HEY");` into `$("a[id^='proxy_']").click();` event. It also did not work.

If it was a path issue, Firebug would have given me a 404 error.

The file structure tree is like the following:

```
|.
|-js
  |-script.js
|-images
  |-proxy_settings
  |-proxy.php
  |-proxy_setting_ie_1.png
  |-proxy_setting_ie_2.png
  |-proxy_setting_ie_1.png
  |-proxy_setting_ie_3.png
  |-proxy_setting_ie_4.png
  |-proxy_setting_ie_5.png
  |-proxy_setting_ie_6.png
  |-proxy_setting_ie_7.png
|-instructionpage.html
|-messageform.php
|-index.php
```

The script does not listen click events although it responds another same event:

This works which resides at the same file (script.js):

```
jQuery("#sendMessage").click(
        function() {
            jQuery("#sendmessage_modal_title").html("Send A Message");
            jQuery("#sendmessage_modal_body").load("messageform.php");
        });
```

Comment: Are the elements you are binding to dynamically added to the html?

Comment: @C-link yes there is. Inside the li element

Comment: What's the output in console?

Comment: @Anton not yet. I am planning to convert it to dynamic after seeing it is working well.

Comment: is the image path relative to the page in which the jquery code is executed?

Comment: @jfriend00 then take a closer look :)

Comment: @jfriend00 modal codes and instructions are on the same page.

Comment: @jfriend00 not important

Comment: Could you try `$(document).on('click','a[id^="proxy_"]',function(){/*Your code*/});`

Comment: Can downvoters please explain what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I apologize you all wasting your valuable time.

I was trying to retrieve the instructions.html into index.php using jQuery's load() function. I moved

```
$(function() {

    $("a[id^='proxy_']").click(
            function() {  
                var b = $(this).data("b");
                var s = $(this).data("s");
                $("#proxy_modal_title").html("Proxy Settings");
                $("#proxy_modal_body").load("images/proxy_settings/proxy.php?b=" + b + "&s=" + s);
            });

});
```

to instructions.html's itself then the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

If the li elements are generated dynamically, you should try this:

```
$(document).on("click", "a[id^='proxy_']", function () {
       //    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

your .php files is in the folder `images/proxy_settings/`

maybe in your `proxy.php` file change the img src to: `echo '<img src="../proxy_setting_' . $_GET['b'] . '_' . $_GET['s'] . '.png " />';`

**Update:**
I dont know why but my Firebug tell me the 404 Not Found Error!
Replace this code into the proxy.php and it should work.

```
echo '<img src="images/proxy_setting_' . $_GET['b'] . '_' . $_GET['s'] . '.png " />';
```

Comment: Tried for your sake. Nothing changed. Even if you were right I should have a 404 error. Nothing happens.

Comment: Could you provide us an live link ^^? Its very strange.

Comment: Ok i have build the code you provide and test on my local computer. You should change this in your proxy.php:
 echo '<img src="images/proxy_setting_' . $_GET['b'] . '_' . $_GET['s'] . '.png " />';